# Run query after page load

Tags: views, database, 7

I have a table of reservations which is built using Views module.

I want to highlight new reservations only 1 time. So I want to run a database update query (function `db_update`) after a page load. I tried to run it in `hook_page_alter()` or in `hook_process()`, but I didn't succeed, because query runs before showing a table. What hook should I use in my case?

Comment: You want to execute a query after page is actually displayed to an user? You know that the only way to do it is to use AJAX, right? If you have higher-level goal in mind, please share, maybe there is a simpler solution.

Comment: To the editor - please use correct syntax. There are `code ticks` for code, don't use **bold** for that. And don't **bold** things in text when it isn't really really needed, you may shift accents to parts of the question OP did not meant as most important.

Comment: Actually, for most uses answer by madhurjya should be enough and AJAX would be a bit of an overkill. My comments tells you how to get what you ask for, but probably not exactly what you really want ;)

Answer (score 2):

hope this will help

```
/**
 * Post process any rendered data.
 *
 * This can be valuable to be able to cache a view and still have some level of
 * dynamic output. In an ideal world, the actual output will include HTML
 * comment based tokens, and then the post process can replace those tokens.
 *
 * Example usage. If it is known that the view is a node view and that the
 * primary field will be a nid, you can do something like this:
 *
 * <!--post-FIELD-NID-->
 *
 * And then in the post render, create an array with the text that should
 * go there:
 *
 * strtr($output, array('<!--post-FIELD-1-->' => 'output for FIELD of nid 1');
 *
 * All of the cached result data will be available in $view->result, as well,
 * so all ids used in the query should be discoverable.
 *
 * This hook can be utilized by themes.
 * @param $view
 *   The view object about to be processed.
 * @param $output
 *   A flat string with the rendered output of the view.
 * @param $cache
 *   The cache settings.
 */
hook_views_post_render(&$view, &$output, &$cache)
    { 
if ($view->name == 'your_view_name') 
    {
   //do your logic
   }}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it happens same as in hook_page_alter...

Comment: In hook_views_post_render, the page is already constructed and in $output. You need to parse $output, and change it according to your logic.